# Show Latitude and Longitude as soon as LocationManger gets it

Tags: android, geolocation, locationmanager

I am developing a Emergency SMS that whenever you access the activity, the GPS will be enabled and the Location of the user will be shown in a textview, then whenever the user presses send it will be sent to the targeted device. now if i am using Network_Provider the Textview will get the Latitude and Longitude as fast as i access my activity and the message will be showin the textview. however, GPS will show an empty textview and empty Location.

Here is my Code:

```
public class SMSmyLocation extends Activity implements OnClickListener, LocationListener{

LocationManager locationManager;
LocationListener locationListner;

Context ctx = SMSmyLocation.this;

TextView tv1, tv2;
Button b1;
EditText ed;

Geocoder geo;
List<Address> addresses;

String address = "";

boolean visibility = false;

double Long = 0,Lad = 0;

SharedPreferences sp;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsmy_location);


    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ESMS);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLocation);


    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendSMS);



    turnGPSOn();

    geo = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);


    if (addresses != null)
    {
        address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0) + " " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1) + " " + addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
        tv1.setText(address);
    }
    else
        tv1.setText("fail");



    b1.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("LM", "Not null");

    double Lad = location.getLatitude();
    double Long = location.getLongitude();

    try {
        addresses = geo.getFromLocation(Lad, Long, 1);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
Log.e("Long", String.valueOf(Long));

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}    
}
```

what can i do to make the system wait till the LocationManger get the Location Coordinates and once it is available, show them in a text. Is threads a good idea and how it can be implemented? please provide tutorial or code with your answer. Thanks for your time and consideration.

Comment: As GPS takes time to retrieve coordinates, so it will take some time .. Network_provider is much efficient in terms of fast location access and battery consumption

Comment: sometimes when i turn off the wireless the network_provider doesnt give me the location, so i need also to consider the GPS

Comment: So use GPS only when network_provider is off, but it will take the time.

Comment: ya, the problem is when i use GPS it will take time to get the Lad and Long and by that time the textview is already set to "fail" because the GPS didn't fetch the coordinates fast. so i need a way to make the system wait till the GPS get the coordinates then add it to the text

Comment: initialize the lat and long value to 0.0, and as soon as you recieve the coordinates (means if lat and long value changes), print them in textView

Comment: I need to put it in a while loop and as soon as Long is bigger than 0 break from it :D Thanks so much for your awesome answer

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_smsmy_location);

    tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ESMS);
    tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.currentLocation);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

}

public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    double Lad = location.getLatitude();
    double Long = location.getLongitude();

    tv2.setText(Lad+", "+Long);
}
```

It's mostly just that within the `onLocationChanged` function you set the textView you want updated. So when the GPS location comes in (yes it can take a long time), it'll trigger this function and update your textView

Comment: if i have stayed in one location for a long time, still the onLoctionChanged function will trigger when the GPS get hold of the coordinates?! Thanks for your reply